# Lemmas, theorems to make non-sp graph into sp graph by addition of vertices?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, reference-works

The left graph is not sp graph because of edges crossing. The middle is a sp graph and the right is a sp graph. Notice that the left can be made into sp graph by addition of the vertex g. So does there exist some lemma or thearems by which to convert non-sp graphs into sp graphs?

[image]